# What is a rim shader used for?

Tags: shaders

What does a rim shader do and what is it used for? In what cases would it make sense to utilize a rim shader?

Answer (score 7):

In the context of graphics programming and shaders, a "rim" shader would be one that focuses on achieving a lighting effect related to the silhouette or other feature/contour edges of an object (crudely, "the outline" of the object). Typically this would be to simulate [rim lighting](http://www.dpreview.com/challenges/Challenge.aspx?ID=2072) ([more examples](http://www.thephotoargus.com/inspiration/30-beautiful-photographs-from-the-rim-lighting-challenge/)), which comes about from [back-lighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlighting_%28lighting_design%29) a subject.

I suppose if you wanted to stretch it, you could consider shaders employ other edge-related effects (such as drawing the outlines on cel shaded scenes) "rim shaders" as well, since they do have something to do with the feature edges of the object. More I think more traditionally the term is used to refer to the lighting effect.